# Why doesn't this jQuery 'closest' code work?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

When I click the 'Generate' button I'd like the `#payment_reference` field value to be generated as per the code. I think the code makes it pretty much clear what I want it to do but for some reason it won't work :(

I've added an `alert` for testing purposes but it just outputs `undefined`

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
// generate payment reference

$( "#generate_payment_reference" ).click(function() {
    $( ".amount_received" ).each(function( index ) {
  var thisAmount = parseFloat($(this).val());
  var paymentRef = '';
        if (thisAmount > 0) {
            paymentRef += $(this).closest(".invoice_reference").val();
   alert($(this).closest(".invoice_reference").val());
        }
  $('#payment_reference').val(paymentRef);
    });
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Client Details</legend>

  <table class="nobord">
    <tr>
      <td>Type:</td>
      <td>Landlord </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name:</td>
      <td>Mr XXX</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Client Bank Account Balance:</td>
      <td>&pound;387.68</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Outstanding Invoice Details</legend>
  <table class="solid" style="margin:5px;">
    <tr>
      <th>Invoice #</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Due Date</th>
      <th>Invoice Total</th>
      <th>Amount Paid</th>
      <th>Amount Due</th>
      <th>Amount Received (&pound;)</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="view_invoice.php?invoice_id=496" target="_blank">496</a>
        <input type="text" class="invoice_reference" value="496">
      </td>
      <td>14/01/16</td>
      <td>14/01/16</td>
      <td>&pound;25.20</td>
      <td>&pound;0.00</td>
      <td>&pound;25.20
        <input type="hidden" name="amount_outstanding[]" value="25.20">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" name="amount_received[]" class="amount_received" value="0.00" max="25.20" required>&nbsp;
        <button class="pay_in_full" type="button">Pay in Full</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="invoice_id[]" value="496">
        <input type="hidden" name="invoice_tenancy_id[]" value="40">
        <input type="hidden" name="invoice_property_id[]" value="119">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="view_invoice.php?invoice_id=497" target="_blank">497</a>
        <input type="text" class="invoice_reference" value="497">
      </td>
      <td>14/01/16</td>
      <td>14/01/16</td>
      <td>&pound;25.20</td>
      <td>&pound;0.00</td>
      <td>&pound;25.20
        <input type="hidden" name="amount_outstanding[]" value="25.20">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" name="amount_received[]" class="amount_received" value="0.00" max="25.20" required>&nbsp;
        <button class="pay_in_full" type="button">Pay in Full</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="invoice_id[]" value="497">
        <input type="hidden" name="invoice_tenancy_id[]" value="40">
        <input type="hidden" name="invoice_property_id[]" value="119">
      </td>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Payment Details</legend>

  <table class="nobord">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="invoice_payment_date">Date:</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="date" id="invoice_payment_date" name="invoice_payment_date" class="datepicker2months" ondblclick="this.value='2016-01-14';" readonly required>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="total_amount_received">Total Amount Received (&pound;):</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" id="total_amount_received" name="total_amount_received" readonly required>
        <input type="hidden" id="client_bank_account_balance" name="client_bank_account_balance" value="387.68" required>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="payment_reference">Payment Reference:</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="payment_reference" readonly>&nbsp;
        <button id="generate_payment_reference" type="button">Generate</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="invoice_payment_use_balance">Pay from Client Bank Account Balance:</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select id="invoice_payment_use_balance" name="invoice_payment_use_balance" required>
          <option value="">Please Select</option>
          <option value="0">No</option>
          <option value="1" selected>Yes</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="invoice_payment_method">Method:</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select id="invoice_payment_method" name="invoice_payment_method" required>
          <option value="">Please Select</option>
          <option value="2" selected>Bank Transfer</option>
          <option value="1">Cash</option>
          <option value="3">Cheque</option>
          <option value="4">Credit Card</option>
          <option value="5">Debit Card</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="invoice_payment_notes">Notes:</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea id="invoice_payment_notes" name="invoice_payment_notes" rows="6" cols="40"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</fieldset>
```

Comment: [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) looks for the nearest *ancestor* element. `.invoice_reference` is not an ancestor. You'll need to do some additional [tree traversal](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/).

Comment: If you tidy up the HTML (which I just did in a JSFiddle with the `Tidy` button), the hierarchy becomes a little clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because your `.invoice_reference` element is not an *ancestor* of your `.amount_received` element. Instead you can go up to the `tr` element and use `find()` to pull the `.invoice_reference` within that:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find(".invoice_reference").val()
```

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie You know, my most upvoted answer here on Stack Overflow was submitted almost 4 years after the question it answered was asked; 1 and a half years after an answer which had over 300 upvotes at the time had been provided. Yet over the course of time my answer has since greatly outvoted the others by a rather boggling 700 votes. This answer I posted 18 seconds after yours, however it wasn't until you left your comment here that I was even aware your answer existed. Time is a rather poor judge of an answer's gumption. Perhaps people favour mine for the way it is worded.

Comment: Actually you have an amazing number average number of upvotes for questions this category. Maybe I need a better photo :)

Comment: My own question was overrun with complaints about my advice on robustness so I have deleted it. Here have another +1. Points on this site are pointless anyway (pun intended)  :)

Answer (score 2):

If  `$(".amount_received").length` is equal to  `$(".invoice_reference").length`, try using `.eq()` with parameter `index`; moving `$('#payment_reference').val(paymentRef);` outside of `.each()` to prevnt value from being overwritten. Note, duplicate closing `</td>`s at `html`.

Note also, not certain is expected result is concatenated string or addition of values at `paymentRef` variable ?

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
// generate payment reference

$( "#generate_payment_reference" ).click(function() {
  var paymentRef = "";
    $( ".amount_received" ).each(function( index ) {
  var thisAmount = parseFloat($(this).val());
  //var paymentRef = '';
        if (thisAmount > 0) {
            paymentRef += $(".invoice_reference").eq(index).val();
        }
  
    });
  $('#payment_reference').val(paymentRef);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<fieldset>
<legend>Client Details</legend>

<table class="nobord"><tr> 
    <td>Type:</td>
 <td>Landlord </td>
  </tr><tr> 
    <td>Name:</td>
 <td>Mr XXX</td>
  </tr><tr> 
    <td>Client Bank Account Balance:</td>
 <td>&pound;387.68</td>
  </tr></table>

</fieldset><fieldset>
<legend>Outstanding Invoice Details</legend><table class="solid" style="margin:5px;"><tr>
    <th>Invoice #</th>
    <th>Date</th>
 <th>Due Date</th>
    <th>Invoice Total</th>
    <th>Amount Paid</th>
 <th>Amount Due</th>
 <th>Amount Received (&pound;)</th>
  </tr><tr>
    <td><a href="view_invoice.php?invoice_id=496" target="_blank">496</a>
 <input type="text" class="invoice_reference" value="496">
 </td>
    <td>14/01/16</td>
 <td>14/01/16</td>
    <td>&pound;25.20</td>
    <td>&pound;0.00</td>
 <td>&pound;25.20
 <input type="hidden" name="amount_outstanding[]" value="25.20">
 </td>
 <td>
 <input type="number" name="amount_received[]" class="amount_received" value="0.00" max="25.20" required>&nbsp;<button class="pay_in_full" type="button">Pay in Full</button>
 <input type="hidden" name="invoice_id[]" value="496">
 <input type="hidden" name="invoice_tenancy_id[]" value="40">
 <input type="hidden" name="invoice_property_id[]" value="119"></td>

  </tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="view_invoice.php?invoice_id=497" target="_blank">497</a>
 <input type="text" class="invoice_reference" value="497">
 </td>
    <td>14/01/16</td>
 <td>14/01/16</td>
    <td>&pound;25.20</td>
    <td>&pound;0.00</td>
 <td>&pound;25.20
 <input type="hidden" name="amount_outstanding[]" value="25.20">
 </td>
 <td>
 <input type="number" name="amount_received[]" class="amount_received" value="0.00" max="25.20" required>&nbsp;<button class="pay_in_full" type="button">Pay in Full</button>
 <input type="hidden" name="invoice_id[]" value="497">
 <input type="hidden" name="invoice_tenancy_id[]" value="40">
 <input type="hidden" name="invoice_property_id[]" value="119"></td>

  </tr></table></fieldset>
<fieldset>
<legend>Payment Details</legend>

<table class="nobord"><tr> 
    <td><label for="invoice_payment_date">Date:</label></td>
 <td>
 <input type="date" id="invoice_payment_date" name="invoice_payment_date" class="datepicker2months" ondblclick="this.value='2016-01-14';" readonly required>
 </td>
  </tr><tr> 
    <td><label for="total_amount_received">Total Amount Received (&pound;):</label></td>
 <td>
 <input type="number" id="total_amount_received" name="total_amount_received" readonly required>
 <input type="hidden" id="client_bank_account_balance" name="client_bank_account_balance" value="387.68" required>
 </td>
  </tr><tr> 
    <td><label for="payment_reference">Payment Reference:</label></td>
 <td>
 <input type="text" id="payment_reference" readonly>&nbsp;<button id="generate_payment_reference" type="button">Generate</button>
 </td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td><label for="invoice_payment_use_balance">Pay from Client Bank Account Balance:</label></td>
 <td><select id="invoice_payment_use_balance" name="invoice_payment_use_balance" required><option value="">Please Select</option><option value="0">No</option><option value="1" selected>Yes</option></select></td></tr><tr>
    <td><label for="invoice_payment_method">Method:</label></td>
 <td><select id="invoice_payment_method" name="invoice_payment_method" required><option value="">Please Select</option><option value="2" selected>Bank Transfer</option><option value="1">Cash</option><option value="3">Cheque</option><option value="4">Credit Card</option><option value="5">Debit Card</option></select></td></tr><tr>
    <td><label for="invoice_payment_notes">Notes:</label></td>
 <td><textarea id="invoice_payment_notes" name="invoice_payment_notes" rows="6" cols="40"></textarea></td></tr></table>

</fieldset>
```

Comment: This is a dangerous technique as it does not scope the `$(".invoice_reference")` search. If you have more `class="invoice_reference"` elements outside this `fieldset` it will go wrong.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie See updated post, added note; `$(".amount_received").length` appear equal to `$(".invoice_reference").length` at `js`

Comment: It will do on this specific example, but what if they have multiple tables on the page? This will recalculate them all. Just my opinion, but scoped searches are safer for maintenance.

Comment: This solves the immediately asked question, so yet another +1 for you. I cannot recommend the technique as being robust, but who give a damn on this website anyway :)